# System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file

Tags: vb.net

Hi programmers colleagues!
Hope you would know how to solve my issue. Time to time not always i get error like in subject when writing to my log file. I got 3 windows services in my solution. Everyone is using same file for logs. Unfortunetly time to time i get the error. My code for logger is showed below. I used synlock and thought that this would be enough but sometimes not. Can you help me what i should change to avoid this issue please?:

```
Public NotInheritable Class Logger

    Private Shared ReadOnly _locker As New Object()

    Public Shared Sub LogIt(ByVal engine As String, ByVal msg As String, ByVal logMessage As String, ByVal Path As String, ByVal IsDebug As Boolean)


            If File.Exists(Path) Then
                If IsDebug Then
                    Debug.Print(DateTime.Now & "> " & "| " & engine & " | " & msg & " | " & logMessage)
                    ' Debug.Print(message)
                Else
                    SyncLock _locker


                        Using w As TextWriter = File.AppendText(Path)

                            'w.WriteLine(message)
                            w.WriteLine(DateTime.Now & "> " & "| " & engine & " | " & msg & " | " & logMessage)
                            w.Flush()
                        End Using
                    End SyncLock
                End If
            Else
                If IsDebug Then
                    '  Debug.Print(message)
                    Debug.Print(DateTime.Now & "> " & "| " & engine & " | " & msg & " | " & logMessage)
                Else
                    SyncLock _locker
                        Using w As TextWriter = File.CreateText(Path)
                            '   w.WriteLine(message)
                            w.WriteLine(DateTime.Now & "> " & "| " & engine & " | " & msg & " | " & logMessage)
                            w.Flush()
                        End Using
                    End SyncLock
                End If
            End If
        End Sub

end class
```

UPDATED:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading

Public NotInheritable Class Logger

    Private Shared ReadOnly _locker As New Mutex(False, "Global\AnyHardToGuessName")


  Public Shared Sub LogIt(ByVal engine As String, ByVal msg As String, ByVal logMessage As String, ByVal Path As String, ByVal IsDebug As Boolean)


        _locker.WaitOne()

        Try
            If File.Exists(Path) Then
                If IsDebug Then
                    Debug.Print(DateTime.Now & "> " & "| " & engine & " | " & msg & " | " & logMessage)
                    ' Debug.Print(message)
                Else
                        Using w As TextWriter = File.AppendText(Path)

                            'w.WriteLine(message)
                            w.WriteLine(DateTime.Now & "> " & "| " & engine & " | " & msg & " | " & logMessage)
                            w.Flush()
                        End Using
                End If
            Else
                If IsDebug Then
                    '  Debug.Print(message)
                    Debug.Print(DateTime.Now & "> " & "| " & engine & " | " & msg & " | " & logMessage)
                Else
                        Using w As TextWriter = File.CreateText(Path)
                            '   w.WriteLine(message)
                            w.WriteLine(DateTime.Now & "> " & "| " & engine & " | " & msg & " | " & logMessage)
                            w.Flush()
                        End Using
                End If
            End If

        Finally
            _locker.ReleaseMutex()
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got 3 windows services in my solution

That produces 3 separate EXEs, they do **not** share the _locker object.  The visibility of .NET objects is restricted to the process in which they are created.  So nothing prevents these programs from trying to open the log file at the same time.  Or trying to create the log file at the same time, you have a bug in the File.Exists usage, it must also be inside the SyncLock statement to prevent a race when two threads both check for file existence at the same time.

By far the best solution is to have each EXE use its own log file so the _locker object is good enough.  If sharing is absolutely essential then you must use a named Mutex to allow these programs to share the same synchronization object across process boundaries.  In other words:

```
 Private Shared ReadOnly _locker As New Mutex(False, "Global\AnyHardToGuessName")

     Public Shared Sub LogIt(...)
        _locker.WaitOne()
        Try
            ''...
        Finally
            _locker.ReleaseMutex()
        End Try
     End Sub
```

Add `Imports System.Threading` at the top of the source file.

Comment: thanks, can you check again my main topic in UPDATED section and check whether is it ok now?

Comment: hi guys, can anyone take a look and confirm please?